# UNION query in Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two fields from two different tables that I am doing a union query between in VBA. I just realized that I need another field to be visible in this query called MARKET SEGMENT.  I am unsure how to add this in because of the union.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ImportIDQuery = "SELECT  PDFVerified.[FORMULARY ID] FROM PDFVerified " & _
"UNION " & _
"SELECT SearchableVerified.[FORMULARY ID] FROM SearchableVerified"
```

Comment: Is market segment in both tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like any other field, add a comma and table.field name.

Data type in both tables MUST Be the same... and be placed in the same ORDER within both selects for the union to work... correctly.

```
ImportIDQuery = "SELECT  PDFVerified.[FORMULARY ID], PDFVerified.[Market Segment] FROM PDFVerified " & _
"UNION " & _
"SELECT SearchableVerified.[FORMULARY ID], SearchableVerified.[Market Segment]
 FROM SearchableVerified"
```